# Need to alter space from postal code in results array

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Hi my requirement need to get postal code from

```
var address= results[0].formatted_address ;
```

this formatted value. 
Because nether land address have "Danzigerkade 12,1013 AP Amsterdam,Netherlands" this kind of address. but i don't want postal code like this"1013 AP" . i need "1013AP" like this.

Please give me the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend parsing the `formatted_address` to get the postal code or any other specific address fields. Instead, you should scan through the `address_components` and check the `types` array of each one to find the address field you need. This is much more reliable than parsing the formatted string.

Once you have the postal code, removing the space is trivial.

To find the postal code for an entry in your `results` array (e.g. `results[0]`), you can use code like this:

```
function getAddressComponent( result, type ) {
    var components = result.address_components;
    for( var i = 0;  i < components.length;  ++i ) {
        var component = components[i], types = component.types;
        for( var k = 0;  k < types.length;  ++k ) {
            if( types[k] == type ){
                return component;
            }
        }
    }
    return {};
}

var component = getAddressComponent( results[0], 'postal_code' );
var postalCode = component ? component.short_name : '';
var postalCodeNoSpace = postalCode.replace( ' ', '' );
console.log( postalCodeNoSpace );
```

Update in reply to your comment:

The code you're asking about with `?` and `:` uses the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) found in JavaScript and many other languages:

```
var postalCode = component ? component.short_name : '';
```

That works just like this longer form that should look more familiar:

```
if( component )
    postalCode = component.short_name;
else
    postalCode = '';
```

The idea was to not try to reference `component.short_name` if `component` itself is `null` or `undefined`, because of course that would be an error. In other words, to protect the program from crashing if `getAddressComponent()` does not find a postal code.

But interestingly enough, there's a bug in the way I was using it. Look at the last line of `getAddressComponent()`:

```
    return {};
```

Originally I was going to return `null` there - and then the code you asked about would have been correct - but for some reason I decided to return an empty object instead. So the code in question wasn't quite right with that change.

One way to fix this would be to go back to what I originally meant to do, and change the last line of `getAddressComponent()` from this:

```
    return {};
```

to:

```
    return null;
```

Comment: Thanks Michael Great.Its working fine. I have one question, am not getting this line please explain. "var postalCode = component ? component.short_name : ''; " .